# What does it mean if my rabbit has a scab on the top of its nose?

Tags: health, rabbits

I have 4 babies who are almost a year old and a buck and a doe as outside pets. They are all in separate cages. I've noticed four of the six rabbits have a single scab on the top of their nose. I've never had any weird problems with my rabbits before except for this year when I bought a flemish giant that had a case of ear mites. (little did I know) I have no clue what these scabs mean. One was a blackish color which I know isn't good. I want to treat them but don't know what to treat them for. Getting a vet around my area is hard because not many around me see rabbits.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate.  If your situation is different, please edit your question to indicate how it is different from the existing question.  Pictures can be very helpful to indicate differences.